# SoftLayer order exception: Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition (64 bit) (17-32 Cores), has a Cores capacity restriction

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

This is the exception I am hitting when trying to place an order for a Windows virtual guest using the SoftLayer python library:

SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition (64 bit) (17-32 Cores), price ID# 175801, has a Cores capacity restriction that does not match the capacity of 4 x 2.0 GHz Cores, price ID# 52139. Please submit prices that are compatible.

The python logic has not changed in a long time in the area that orders this virtual guest and we have not seen issues before. Was there a recent API change or virtual guest ordering restriction that was put in place?  For reference, we are obtaining the price IDs for these options before placing the order:

package id: 46

`{
"os_type": "OS_WINDOWS_2012_FULL_STD_64_BIT",
"core_type": "GUEST_CORES_4",
"ip_size": "1_IP_ADDRESS",
"bandwidth": "BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2",
"ram_size": "RAM_8_GB",
"reboot_type": "REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE",
"uplink_speed": "1_GBPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINK",
"vpn_type": "UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT",
"host_monitor_size": "MONITORING_HOST_PING_AND_TCP_SERVICE",
"disk_type": "GUEST_DISK_100_GB_LOCAL",
"notify_method": "NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET",
"is_auto_notify": "AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION",
"vulner_report": "NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING"
}`

Comment: your python logic may not change, but softlayer could have added restrictions to the items or descontinue the item for new orders, when you come across with issue like this you need to check that you are still able to order those items using the control portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope not misunderstanding you, but How are you getting the identifiers?

I think that here is the issue:

> - "os_type": "OS_WINDOWS_2012_FULL_STD_64_BIT",
> - "core_type": "GUEST_CORES_4",

**The 175801 price is only for 17-32 Cores**, you need to use another identifier for the OS because **you are ordering 4 cores** and you need to use a price which support the core's capacity that you choose

Can you try with this id: **175797** instead of **175801**

Comment: I get the item prices for package id 46 `get_client(sl_user, sl_api).call('Product_Package', 'getItemPrices', id=pkg_id, mask=<our mask>)` and from there look for the item keynames for the options I am specifying above.  So maybe package id 46 changed?

Comment: I don't think so, **there exists three prices for: OS_WINDOWS_2012_FULL_STD_64_BIT
the first for servers with core: 1-16 second for cores:17-32 and the third for: 33-56**. your script is getting the price for OS core: 17-32 and you are ordering a server with 4 cores (So the exception is being raised for this reason), you need to use the price for 1-16 cores, which would be the price that I sent in my answer

Comment: This solved my issue.  I had to expand my mask to see that there are 2 fields called capacityRestrictionMinimum and capacityRestrictionMaximum.  Not sure if this was recently added to the SL API or whether the code has been getting lucky and the 1-16 core capacity image was always first in the item list.  Checking for these values and choosing the correct one resolved my issue.

Comment: I believe that you got lucky :) because I each OS has this restrictions, but it's great that you solved